# Mule 4 database connector taking more time to execute a stored procedure

Tags: database-connection, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to create a  simple flow where i need to execute a procedure and return the data to a client application via mule. The flow is build in mule4 , but unfortunately the database connector(1.14.3) is taking more time and looks like its stuck . Did anyone encountered this scenario. I tried downgrading the connector but no luck . Is it something to do with JDK version to ?

Please feel free to answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="aeaca3b3-daa8-4cfd-b61b-127bf9052392" >
        <db:oracle-connection host="ldap://ldap-ldprd.xxxxx.com" port="5000" user="xxxx" password="xxxxxxx" serviceName="cn=OracleContext,dc=xxxxx,dc=com/xxxxx" />
    </db:config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="387b0736-3bd4-42c4-b8c3-6f2f1be1a9f7" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="mytestFlow" doc:id="ccb8fc91-17a4-44d0-a4b1-c1c09338299f" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="4484ad0c-90f5-4ac3-ad34-32671f94662e" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/getdetails"/>
        <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="33ec085e-0156-457d-be1c-cacba672f643" config-ref="Database_Config" queryTimeout="10">
            <non-repeatable-stream />
            <reconnect-forever />
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[{call APPS.GET_USER_BANNER_MSG (:bannerMessage, :P_ERROR_MESSAGE)}]]></db:sql>
            <db:output-parameters >
                <db:output-parameter key="bannerMessage" customType="CURSOR" type="LONGVARCHAR"/>
                <db:output-parameter key="P_ERROR_MESSAGE" type="VARCHAR" />
            </db:output-parameters>
        </db:stored-procedure>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Thanks,

SID

Comment: You are not providing any details of the actual issue. What does it mean it is 'taking more time'? How much time **exactly**? Compared to what? Did it work differently before? Does the issue reproduce every time, sometimes, only once? Have you tested the stored procedure with some other tool and compared the results? Where are the connector configurations, the flow, the database schema, the stored procedure definition? Which database and JDBC driver and versions are you using? For additional troublshooting I would capture some thread dumps just in case while the query is executing.

Comment: And why would you assume an issue with the JDK -which by the way you didn't share which JDK and version is- or assume someone can tell if it is without any information at all of the issue? Are you seeing any symptoms or messages related to JDK? Remember that people here don't know what you know nor what you are seeing unless you share it. And please edit the question to add additional information.

Comment: Its an oracle proc , i tried executing the same from Toad , it returns data in less than 2 sec.What does it mean it is 'taking more time'? - The api hit is going like more than 20 mins and more  with no response .Compared to what? Did it work differently before? in 3.9 version of mule ,it fetches the data in 2-3 seconds.Does the issue reproduce every time, sometimes, only once? Have you tested the stored procedure with some other tool and compared the results?Yes  The results are fetched within seconds.

Comment: Where are the connector configurations, the flow, the database schema, the stored procedure definition?The sample code snippet is attached in the question section.hich database and JDBC driver and versions are you using? JDK 8 and database connector 1.14.0

Comment: The flow does nothing after the stored procedure call. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It should return the data in console in output variable rght

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255119/discussion-between-sidh-and-aled).

Comment: This is a know issue. There are problems with the stored procedure operations in mule 4. I have also observed this issue in the same version. There is an article by Mulesoft team saying upgrading to 1.14.2 helps. But it doesn't. Sometimes you can be right but hard to back it up with compelling evidence. Cheers.